# How long does Capitao's fire last for?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

This is in relation to his crossbow with the damaging bolt. If you have information on the micro smoke too, that would also be helpful, but I'm mainly looking for the damaging one.

Comment: @n_palum ah too bad. but at least I know smoke's canister lasts for around 30 secs, so I should start smoking at the 30 sec mark

Comment: @n_palum yeah I saw your answer for the other question. At least I have an answer for that now. But I'll just wait for an answer for Capitao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I went and did some research and unlocked Capitao.

Just as a first, [here is a video](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/4vwn21/psa_capitaos_fire_bolt_radius/) showing the burn radius of the fire bolt.

And then based on my observations/tests and confirmation from sources such as [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/4xrouh/capitaos_bolt_last/) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeinkssTIbI), **the fire bolt lasts for about 12 seconds, and kills in about 2.**

**The smoke lasts for about 10 seconds.** The smoke doesn't prevent visibility as much as a smoke grenade, *while you're outside of it*, but when you enter its radius it's a 0 visibility.